# Is there a way to set up an Exchange mailbox to collect email "anonymously"?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

What my company wants is for an email box to be set up so that when an email is sent to it, the From: field would be blanked out so that it would be anonymous. Is there any way to do this either through Exchange or third party software?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Exchange 2010 try the following in the Exchange Management Shell.

`New-TransportRule -Name "Remove Header: From" -SentTo RecipientAlias -RemoveHeader "From"`

This should create you a Hub Transport rule to remove the *From* header. All you need to do is change **RecipientAlias** to the actual alias of this anonymous receiving mailbox.

Comment: Thanks for the input - that indeed sounds like what I am trying to do, but unfortunately we are running 2k3. I'm assuming this wouldn't be a valid option for me?

Comment: No, transport rules were new in Exchange 2007 and improved in Exchange 2010. Now I know it's Exchange 2003, I'll have a poke around.