# Anonymous Exchange 2010 Inbox

Tags: email, exchange, exchange-2010

I've set up a mailbox like `suggestionbox@domain.com` that we would like people to be able to send emails to anonymously, creating a Transport Rule in Exchange 2010 as in this question: [Is there a way to set up an Exchange mailbox to collect email "anonymously"?](https://serverfault.com/questions/200889/is-there-a-way-to-set-up-an-exchange-mailbox-to-collect-email-anonymously)

This seems to work for external senders (when I send to this mailbox from my gmail account, the `From` field is appropriately stripped out) but this does not seem to work for internal senders... when I send to this mailbox from my Exchange email account, it still shows me as the sender.

Can anyone suggest how to correct this so it anonymises internal senders as well?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want these emails to appear anonymous?

Comment: Request from HR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that an Exchange email sent internally is able to be modified this way. The other method has to do with transport rules, which are implemented by connectors.  This may be a case of using the wrong tool for the job.

Perhaps something along the lines of a comment form on an internal web page would be better suited for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Exchange lab in front of me, but you should look into creating a server side transport rule to redirect the emails to a second mailbox, the final destination mailbox, and while doing that, stripping the incoming email address or replacing it with the 'suggestionbox@domain.com' address.